# JSF: How to display BufferedImage on page?

Tags: java, jsf

I need to display a BufferedImage object on page. How to do that ?
I'm thinking about saving temporary file in WEB-INF and get that image as resource. Is this a right way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of library are you using? If you use [`Richfaces`](http://jboss.org/richfaces), you can use the [`<a4j:mediaOutput>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/mediaOutput.jsf) component for this kind of things, without generating any external files...